# get request, looping and sending data outside get request in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, cheerio

I'm trying to code a scraper that will load a bunch of keywords and search them on Amazon. I then need to use the keyword and search on the page for it to see how many instances of it there is.

I've searched around and seen people use the term asynchronous function and callback but I don't know what those mean and every time the explanation is way over my head. I tried googling those terms and I still don't understand.

Here's my code and obviously it does not work. If there's a simple way to accomplish what I'm trying to do with my current knowledge that would be great.

```
// load modules
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

//split into array
keywords = ["books", "bags", "shoes"];

// loop task for every keyword
global.i
for (i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) { 
console.log(keywords[i] + " was loaded.");

// get request
request('https://www.amazon.com/s/?url=field-keywords=' + keywords[i], function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html); 

    // try to use the keyword (doesn't work)
    console.log(keywords[i]);

  } // end get request
}); // get request end

// Try to use the html outside get request (doesn't work)
console.log(html);

} // loop end
```

Comment: Why you've trying to use for loops to make all requests in the same time, may be Amazon has limits for requests per second try to request one by one with interval.

Comment: What else should I use then? It seems to work so far if I do it with less than 1000 keywords which is all I need.

Comment: I don't think Amazon allows that

Comment: Well if I get blocked I will do that. In the meantime can you help me with what I actually asked?

Comment: but may be you can request one by one after request for keyword1 success wait x seconds and request keyword2. but this shouldn't work if there are limitations.

Comment: What i can provide is a code to request one by one with interval between. but i can't promise it should work perfectly.

Comment: what would that code be?

Comment: To make requests one by one create a function with name and put your request function inside and call this function inside with callback with increment number.

Comment: See code here https://jsfiddle.net/vncxfx0s/24/

Comment: this is what i get when running your code http://pastebin.com/HYPZEQEs

Comment: That's maybe because `cheerio.load(html)` really i don't know what is `cheerio` module working for.

Comment: Sorry, my function code not fired i forget to start requesting with `requestNext()` https://jsfiddle.net/vncxfx0s/25/

Answer (score 0):

From the request you send, the Server(here Amazon) takes some time to respond. In general that would be less than 600ms. So, instead of waiting for that amount of time, javascript continues its execution to next line. So, when you are in that for loop, you make a request., Script continues execution. 2 more requests are made. So all the 3 requests are made, awaiting response. in the mean time, execution continues to next line.
At this point of time, the variable html is not defined anywhere in the application scope. So it did threw error. Even after the 3 responses are received, the variable html will not be defined since it is scoped inside the response function. You can use variable html inside the callback function of request as below

```
// load modules
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

//split into array
keywords = ["books", "bags", "shoes"];

// loop task for every keyword
for (i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) { 
    console.log("loading", keywords[i]);

    // get request
    request('https://www.amazon.com/s/?url=field-keywords=' + keywords[i],     
        function (error, response, html) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var $ = cheerio.load(html); 
                console.log(keywords[i]);
                console.log(html);
            }
        }
    );
}
```